# Seeking a log4j2.properties appender, but not the rolling appender?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j2

Question 1:

I have been looking everywhere for an example of a log4j2.properties file that uses an appender to write to a file - but **not** the rolling appender.

I already roll the files through syslog and I don't understand why I have to define an entire separate rolling strategy just to write to a single file.

Is there such a beast?

Question 2:

If I can't get an answer for Question 1, then I have been looking for a comprehensive listing of all the appenders possible in a log4j2.properties file.  I see plenty of examples of all the different rolling appenders, but I was looking for  appenders that are not specific either to rolling or console.

All I've been able to find so far are properties files with rolling appenders, or non-rolling XML files.

(summary)

Either the answer to Question 1 or Question 2 would be amazing.  The bottom line is that I'm looking for something that doesn't involve rolling, that would be put in a .properties file (specifically for Elasticsearch).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question 1:*** I have an very simple log file with just log everything to a file - not rolling file.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{dd} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.aavn.viking.feedback360
logger.file.level = info
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

About the rolling file strategy I think it is used for delete the log file when it meet specific business like over 30 days, the accumulated file over 100 MB, or something else.

***Question 2:*** There are some appenders that you can put on log4j2.properties file except console, rolling file and file such as: `CassandraAppender`,`FailoverAppender`, `FlumeAppender`, `JDBCAppender`, `JMS Appende`r, `HttpAppender` etc. The link below is for more information about another appenders.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

P/s: If you want run my log4j2.properties, you must add`logging.config=src/main/resources/log4j2.properties` to the application.properties
and add log4j2 dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```